# Problems with validation in jQuery

Tags: jquery, validation

Basing this example

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery: Check if Textarea is empty 3</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
            <label for="comments">Comments:</label>
            <textarea name="comments" id="comments"></textarea>
        </form>
        <input name="check" id="check" type="submit" value="OK" />
        <input type="reset" value="Cancelar" onclick="$('form')[0].reset() "/>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#check').click(function() {
                if ( $('#comments').val() == '' )
                {
                    alert('Empty!!!');
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('Contains: ' + $('#comments').val() );
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I did this page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Formulario demo 3</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"  src="js/validador.js"> </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="inicio">
            <div class="div_formulario">
                <form name="formulario" id="formulario" class="formulario" action="" method="post">
                <ul>
                    <li>Nombre o razón social: <span>(*)</span></li>
                    <li><input name="nombre" id="nombre" type="text"></li>
                    <li>E-Mail <span>(*)</span></li>
                    <li><input name="email" id="email" type="text"></li>
                    <li>Tipo de evento: <span>(*)</span></li>
                    <li><input name="evento" id="evento" value="empresarial" type="radio"> Empresarial
                    <input name="evento" id="evento" value="empresarial" type="radio"> Particular</li>
                    <li>Me interesa consultar sobre:<span>(*)</span> </li>
                    <li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="consulta" id="consulta" value="catering"/>
                        Catering    </li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="consulta" id="consulta" value="salones"/>
                        Salones</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="consulta" id="consulta" value="musica"/>
                        M&uacute;sica </li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="consulta" id="consulta" value="fotografia"/>
                        Fotograf&iacute;a     </li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="consulta" id="consulta"  value="decoracion"/>
                        Decoraci&oacute;n </li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="consulta" id="consulta" value="dj"/>
                        DJ </li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="consulta" id="consulta" value="show"/>
                        Show </li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="consulta" id="consulta" value="videos"/>
                        Videos </li>
                    </li>
                    <li> Zona donde desea el evento:<span>(*)</span></li>
                        <li>
                        <select name="ubicacion" id="ubicacion">
                            <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
                            <option value="caba">CABA</option>
                            <option value="gba">GBA</option>
                            <option value="fueradegba">Fuera de GBA, Bs As</option>
                            <option value="interior">Interior</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                    <label for="comments">Comments:</label>
                        <textarea name="comments" id="comments">
                        </textarea>
                    </form>
                    <li class="botones"><input name="check" id="check" type="submit" value="OK" /></li>
                    <li class="botones"><input type="reset" value="Cancelar" onclick="$('form')[0].reset()"/></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### File validador.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#formulario").submit(function () {
        if($("#nombre").val().length < 4) {
            alert("El nombre debe tener más de 3 caracteres");
            return false;
        }
        if($("#email").val().length < 1) {
            alert("La dirección e-mail es obligatoria");
            return false;
        }
        if($("#email").val().indexOf('@', 0) == -1 || $("#email").val().indexOf('.', 0) == -1) {
            alert("La dirección parece incorrecta");
            return false;
        }
        if($("#evento").is(':checked')) { } else {
            alert("Indique el tipo de evento");
            return false;
        }
        if($("#consulta").is(':checked')) { } else {
            alert("Indique al menos un item");
            return false;
        }
        if($("#ubicacion option:selected").val() == "") {
            alert("La zona es obligatoria");
            return false;
        }
            $('#check').click(function() {
                if ( $('#comments').val() == '' )
                {
                alert('Empty!!!');
                }
                else
                {
                alert('Contains: ' + $('#comments').val() );
                }
            });
        return false;
    });
});
```

#### File estilo.css

```
.html, body {
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
}

.inicio {
    width:600px;
    height:100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
}

.formulario ul {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding-top:20px;
    list-style-type:none;
}

.formulario ul li {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    height:25px;
    line-height:25px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding-top:5px;
}

.formulario ul li.botones {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Validation me with errors because of radio buttons. "Type" must be selected in "Business" and checkboxes
of "I'm interested Request" must be in "Catering" for me to take them as valid.

I also validate a wrong message textarea: if empty, it should display the message "Empty!",
but it appears that the textarea returns empty content "Contains".

How I can fix these errors?

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle demonstrating the error so it's easier for people to help you!

Comment: BTW, provide only relevant to your issue code, not your whole site...

Comment: my code http://jsfiddle.net/andoporto/7GwyW/

Comment: original code http://jsfiddle.net/andoporto/R49qJ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues:

```
<input name="evento" id="evento" value="empresarial" type="radio"> Empresarial 
<input name="evento" id="evento" value="empresarial" type="radio"> Particular
```

`id` must be unique on a page. Change the `id` attributes to something like `evento_empresarial` and `evento_particular`. In addition, you have the same value for each radio option. I presume the `value` of the second one should be `particular`.

In addition, please include `label` elements for each field, and make sure the `for` attribute of the label is the ID of its associated field. For example, in the code above, you should have something like:

```
<input name="evento" id="evento_empresarial" value="empresarial" type="radio"> <label for="evento_empresarial">Empresarial</label> 
<input name="evento" id="evento_particular" value="particular" type="radio"> <label for="evento_particular">Particular</label>
```

This is not only semantically correct, but by adding a label with an appropriate `for` attribute, you allow the user to click the entire label to select the option, rather than only being able to click the little bitty radio button control. You should do that for all of your checkboxes as well, and correct all of the IDs on those checkboxes while you're at it. :)

As far as the issue that you're reporting (the textarea reporting "contains:" when it you're expecting "empty"), the `textarea` element contains whitespace as you've written it in the markup:

While you could certainly write the textarea to not contain spaces, in general, you should always trim whitespace from your inputs before validating, unless it's whitespace dependent (as in code samples). On your validation function, try:

```
if ( $('#comments').val().trim() == '' )
```

See updated jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7GwyW/1/

Hope this helps.

Comment: updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/andoporto/WZC8Y/ but the textarea don´t validate correctly and I must click four times for exit to alert "contains "

Comment: I delete else of if ( $('#comments').val() == '' ) but the validation of textarea don´t work http://jsfiddle.net/andoporto/7dAUn/

Comment: You're adding the `click` handler inside of the form's `submit` handler. You should extract it to be outside the scope of the form validator. In addition, there were a number of markup problems. I removed the styles so it's easier to see the structure; you can add them back in. http://jsfiddle.net/7dAUn/1/

Comment: The problem is that validates me wrong the Name field, should enable entering letters should not allow entry of numbers and must have more than 3 characters, does not work. While the value validates me "q1245" and "1245y", is that when the field has more than 3 characters extension it accept the value, even with numbers, but wrong.

Comment: Where in your code are you checking for those conditions? The only validation I see on `nombre` is `if ($("#nombre").val().length < 4)`. If you want to test for no numbers, you'll need to match something, possibly using a regex.

Comment: Glad it was useful. Please feel free to accept this answer if it answered your question.